# Yahoo Messanger API

Tags: java

Where i have to download YMSG api for java?..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenYMSG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openymsg/) or [jYMSG](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/)